# While using spring form am getting "equal symbol expected " issuse in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Actually while mapping the path in input field iam getting this exception,
here i will add the jsp page in which am getting exepetion

`<form:label path="firstName">
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </form:label>
              <form:input type="text" path="firstName" required autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: the exception is org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp (line: 35, column: 64) equal symbol expected

Comment: input tagis my 35th line

Comment: use required="required" instead of only required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your input

This is your input

```
<form:input type="text" path="firstName" required autocomplete="off" />
```

This is the expected input:

```
<form:input type="text" path="firstName" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
```